# ¿Cómo puedo corregir el resultado de SUM para esta simple consulta en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

¡Buen día a todos!

¿Pueden ayudarme a corregir esta consulta en MySQL? Simplemente estoy generando una tabla pivote y quiero retornar con SUM la suma de cada fila, pero actualmente me arroja un valor incorrecto. Las tablas son las siguientes:

*lab_registered_problems*

```
+--------+------------+------------+----------+
| id_lab | id_problem | subproblem | weighing |
+--------+------------+------------+----------+
| 123456 |         55 |          1 |       20 |
| 123456 |         55 |          2 |       30 |
| 123456 |         55 |          3 |       50 |
+--------+------------+------------+----------+
```

*lab_registered_users*

```
+--------+---------+
| id_lab | id_user |
+--------+---------+
| 123456 |   User1 |
| 123456 |   User2 |
| 123456 |   User3 |
+--------+---------+
```

*lab_user_scores*

```
+--------+------------+------------+---------+-------+
| id_lab | id_problem | subproblem | id_user | score |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+-------+
| 123456 |         55 |          1 |   User1 |   100 |
| 123456 |         55 |          2 |   User2 |    50 |
+--------+------------+------------+---------+-------+
```

La consulta SQL es la siguiente:

```
SELECT lab_registered_users.id_user,
MAX(IF(lab_user_scores.id_problem = 55 AND lab_user_scores.subproblem = 1 AND lab_user_scores.id_user = lab_registered_users.id_user,lab_user_scores.score * lab_registered_problems.weighing / 100.0,0)) AS "55/1",
MAX(IF(lab_user_scores.id_problem = 55 AND lab_user_scores.subproblem = 2 AND lab_user_scores.id_user = lab_registered_users.id_user,lab_user_scores.score * lab_registered_problems.weighing / 100.0,0)) AS "55/2",
MAX(IF(lab_user_scores.id_problem = 55 AND lab_user_scores.subproblem = 3 AND lab_user_scores.id_user = lab_registered_users.id_user,lab_user_scores.score * lab_registered_problems.weighing / 100.0,0)) AS "55/3",
SUM(lab_user_scores.score * lab_registered_problems.weighing / 100.0) AS total_score
FROM lab_registered_users 
INNER JOIN lab_user_scores ON lab_user_scores.id_lab = lab_registered_users.id_lab 
INNER JOIN lab_registered_problems ON lab_registered_problems.id_lab = lab_registered_users.id_lab AND lab_registered_problems.id_problem = lab_user_scores.id_problem AND lab_registered_problems.subproblem = lab_user_scores.subproblem
WHERE lab_registered_users.id_lab = 123456
GROUP BY lab_registered_users.id_user
```

La cual me genera la siguiente tabla:

```
+---------+---------+---------+--------+-------------+
| id_user |   55/1  |   55/2  |  55/3  | total_score |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+-------------+
|   User1 | 20.0000 |  0.0000 | 0.0000 |     35.0000 |
|   User2 |  0.0000 | 15.0000 | 0.0000 |     35.0000 |
|   User3 |  0.0000 |  0.0000 | 0.0000 |     35.0000 |
+--------+----------+---------+--------+-------------+
```

Sin embargo, lo que quiero conseguir es lo siguiente:

```
+---------+---------+---------+--------+-------------+
| id_user |   55/1  |   55/2  |  55/3  | total_score |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+-------------+
|   User1 | 20.0000 |  0.0000 | 0.0000 |     20.0000 |
|   User2 |  0.0000 | 15.0000 | 0.0000 |     15.0000 |
|   User3 |  0.0000 |  0.0000 | 0.0000 |      0.0000 |
+--------+----------+---------+--------+-------------+
```

¡Muchas gracias por tu valioso tiempo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En base al resultado que deseas obtener y a la relación lógica que deben tener las tablas, veo varios detalles:

1. Dado que quieres que aparezcan todos los *usuarios*, ambos [*join*][1] debieran ser `left outer join` y no `inner join`
2. Falta una condición en el *join* de la tabla `lab_user_scores`, de manera que se incluyan en el resultado solamente aquellos registros que pertenecen al usuario de la tabla `lab_registered_users`
3. Lo anterior hace innecesaria la condición `AND lab_user_scores.id_user = lab_registered_users.id_user` en los `if`, que supongo estaba allí por la manera en que se ha hecho el `join`.
4. Finalmente, la manera en la que haces la *suma* me deja en duda... si un usuario tiene más de un registro en la tabla `lab_registered_problems` para algún sub-tipo particular, el resultado incluirá solamente el valor máximo de la fórmula en la columna del sub-tipo de problema, pero la sumatoria incluirá todos los registros. Eso podría parecer inconsistente para un usuario. Desconozco si puede darse, pero si es el caso, invitaría a definir bien cómo debe funcionar la consulta.
5. Lo anterior también aplica si hay *problemas* que no sean del tipo `55`. Estos se incluirán en la suma, pero no aparecerán en ninguna columna.

En resumen, aplicando mis cambios, la consulta quedaría algo así:

```
SELECT   lab_registered_users.id_user
       , MAX(IF(lab_user_scores.id_problem = 55 AND lab_user_scores.subproblem = 1, lab_user_scores.score * lab_registered_problems.weighing / 100.0,0)) AS "55/1"
       , MAX(IF(lab_user_scores.id_problem = 55 AND lab_user_scores.subproblem = 2, lab_user_scores.score * lab_registered_problems.weighing / 100.0,0)) AS "55/2"
       , MAX(IF(lab_user_scores.id_problem = 55 AND lab_user_scores.subproblem = 3, lab_user_scores.score * lab_registered_problems.weighing / 100.0,0)) AS "55/3"
       , SUM(lab_user_scores.score * lab_registered_problems.weighing / 100.0) AS total_score
  FROM lab_registered_users 
       left join lab_user_scores ON lab_user_scores.id_lab = lab_registered_users.id_lab and lab_registered_users.id_user = lab_user_scores.id_user
       left join lab_registered_problems ON lab_registered_problems.id_lab = lab_registered_users.id_lab AND lab_registered_problems.id_problem = lab_user_scores.id_problem AND lab_registered_problems.subproblem = lab_user_scores.subproblem
 WHERE lab_registered_users.id_lab = 123456
 GROUP BY lab_registered_users.id_user
```

Comment: Hola @jachguate ! gracias por tu respuesta, estaba confundiendo los conceptos de JOIN por lo que noté. Básicamente lo que estoy haciendo es un scoreboard donde hay problemas y subproblemas asociados a un laboratorio, los estudiantes se registran en un laboratorio, luego responden y se les asigna puntaje. Entonces requería poder contabilizar bien el puntaje total. ¡Muchas gracias nuevamente!